# How can I download a json file via API every minute without it getting stopped by asyncio?

Tags: python, json, api, python-asyncio

For the next weeks to come I want to download every minute market data from Deribit as a .json file via their API.

Somehow my loop stops halfway trough its execution.

I'm new to python and this might be far away from being the best way to do this so I'm open for any advise,

Download market data from deribit works fine if I run the get_instruments or get_book_summary_by_currency script once and on its own.

However, I want to run both scripts simultaniously every 1min (or maybe 5min) basicly for the next weeks. Therefore I created a third main script as you can see below.

When I run this I get the first json file from my get_instruments script but not the other one, apparentely the script stops after executing get_instruments which I guess has something to do with asyncio.

Furthermore I also don't understand why it doesn't print the time even though it's the first command in that function.

I don't recieve any error messages.

Thanks for your help!

```
MAIN:

import schedule
import time
import get_instruments
import get_book_summary_by_currency

def job():
    print('Time now'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"))
    get_instrument.py
    get_book_summary_by_currency.py

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


GET_INSTRUMENTS:

import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import time

msg_instruments = \
{
  "jsonrpc" : "2.0",                                  
  "id" : time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"),            
  "method" : "public/get_instruments",                
  "params" : {                                        
    "currency" : "BTC",                               
    "kind" : "option",                                
    "expired" : "false"                               
  }
}

async def call_api(msg,filename):
  async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
    await websocket.send(msg)
    while websocket.open:
      response = await websocket.recv()
      with open(filename,'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response,outfile,indent=4)

savename = 'Instruments_'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")+'.json'
asyncio.run(call_api(json.dumps(msg_instruments),savename))


GET_BOOK_SUMMARY_BY_CURRENCY:

import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import time

msg_book_summary = \
{
  "jsonrpc" : "2.0",                                 
  "id" : time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"),           
  "method" : "public/get_book_summary_by_currency",   
  "params" : {                                        
    "currency" : "BTC",                               
    "kind" : "option",                                
    "expired" : "false"                               
  }
}


async def call_api(msg,filename):
  async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
    await websocket.send(msg)
    while websocket.open:
      response = await websocket.recv()
     with open(filename,'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response,outfile,indent=4)

savename = 'Book_summary_'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")+'.json'
asyncio.run(call_api(json.dumps(msg_book_summary),savename))
```

Comment: The schedule module doesn't look like it's compatible with asyncio. Also, what is `get_instrument.py` intended to achieve, exactly? It doesn't look like correct Python.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i figured it out by now :) i was stuck in the while loop. by adding a simple break everything works fine now.

import get_instruments and import get_book_summary_by_currency are different scripts (seperate files). but yeah, i needed to delete the .py

Comment: Good to hear! You might want to write up an answer for posterity, or delete the question, so it doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by now. It never left the while loop. By adding a simple break everything works...